# Don't want mysql to auto cast String to Integer

Tags: mysql, type-conversion

I came across this auto typecasting of MYSQL from String to Integer seems to me weird.

```
mysql> select * from `isps` where `id` = '3ca6fb49-9749-3099-b30d-19ce56349ad6' OR `unique_id` = '3ca6fb49-9749-3099-b30d-19ce56349ad6';
+----+--------------------------------------+---------------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | unique_id                            | name          | code         | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+--------------------------------------+---------------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  3 | ee8db3be-1bf7-3440-8add-37232cfc4ecb | TTN           | ttn          | 2019-09-26 08:12:14 | 2019-09-26 08:12:14 |
|  7 | 3ca6fb49-9749-3099-b30d-19ce56349ad6 | ONE BROADBAND | onebroadband | 2019-09-26 08:12:14 | 2019-09-26 08:12:14 |
+----+--------------------------------------+---------------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I had not expected result with **id = 3** can anyone help with this.

### DataType in my database

```
id - BIGINT
unique_id - varchar(200)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast `id` to a string before comparing.

```
select * from `isps` where CAST(`id` AS CHAR) = '3ca6fb49-9749-3099-b30d-19ce56349ad6' OR `unique_id` = '3ca6fb49-9749-3099-b30d-19ce56349ad6';
```

Note that this will slow down the query significantly, since it won't be able to use the index on the `id` column.

Comment: Hi I may even pass an integer to this query then it reads as id = '4' or unique_id = '4' will that work

Comment: That will work with this. If you write `WHERE CAST(id AS CHAR) = '4'` it will work.